# Trying Junit for the first time and failing

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to use Junit for the first time but I'm facing some unexpected failure.

Here is the failure message:
`org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <2> but was: <19>.`

It would be great if someone will be able to help me understand where is my error.
I spend more than 30 minutes in trying to understand the reason behind it and I can't. I guess I need to do a minor change somewhere.

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }
    public int getDenomonator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public Fraction(int n, int d) {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = d;

    }
    /**
     * This method is adding other fraction
     * to our current(this) fraction
     * @param otherFraction
     */
    public void add(Fraction otherFraction) {
        int a = numerator;
        int b = denominator;
        int c = otherFraction.getNumerator();
        int d = otherFraction.getDenomonator();
        numerator = a * d + b * c;
        denominator = b * d;

        int min = denominator;

        if (numerator < denominator) {
            min = numerator;                
        }

        int commonDiv = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= min; i++) {
            if ((numerator % i == 0) && (denominator % 1 == 0)) {
                commonDiv = i;
            }
        }

        numerator = numerator / commonDiv;
        denominator = denominator / commonDiv;

        if (numerator == 0) denominator = 1;
    }

}
```

Test:

```
class FreactionTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(3,4);
        Fraction f2 = new Fraction(5,6);
        f1.add(f2);
        assertEquals(f1.getNumerator(),19);
        assertEquals(f1.getDenomonator(),12);
    }

    @Test
    void testAddNegative() {
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(3,4);
        Fraction f2 = new Fraction(-3,4);
        f1.add(f2);
        assertEquals(f1.getNumerator(),0);
        assertEquals(f1.getDenomonator(),1);
    }
}
```

I expected the code to run successfully.

Comment: Can you show the code for `Fraction` class?

Comment: What do you mean run successfully? The code is running (according to the message you get). Do you expect the test case to pass? Then change `getNumerator` method to return the correct result.

Comment: The error message is telling you that where it expected 19, the value was actually 2. Please [try to debug it yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254094/question-that-can-be-solved-using-basic-debugging) first. Debugging is a crucial skill to develop, and it'll only get harder if you don't learn. And the best way to learn is by practice. If you trace it down to a specific line you don't understand, that could make a good question for this site.

Comment: Your test shows that the method returns two instead of nineteen as you expect it to. Also you have interchanged the two arguments.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I got my expected/actual backwards.

Comment: JUnit seems to be serving its purpose for you already, since it has demonstrated that your code returns the wrong result.

Comment: `denominator % 1 == 0` <— This is presumably not the condition you intended to be checking.

Comment: Thanks, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your expected/actual backwards in the call to `assertEquals()`.  According to the docs [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double)), the first argument is the expected value, and the second argument is the actual value.  So you need to switch your arguments, since right now you're hard-coding the `actual` result to be 19.  The call you're trying to test should be the second argument, and the value you expect to be returned should be the first argument.  You're doing it in all your other `assertEquals()` calls also, so be sure to change those as well.